# .htaccess files possibly conflicting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one .htaccess file in the public_html folder of my server that lets me keep my primary domain in a subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mrmikeanderson.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mrmikeanderson/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mrmikeanderson/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mrmikeanderson.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mrmikeanderson/index.php [L]
```

In that subfolder is another .htaccess with more rewrites to turn urls ending with things like /index.php?page=about into just /about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=home
RewriteRule portfolio index.php?page=portfolio
RewriteRule resume index.php?page=resume
RewriteRule about index.php?page=about
RewriteRule contact index.php?page=contact
```

The last four pages work, but my rewrite for just the domain name (\^$) is broken. Everything works on my local MAMP server, but the first .htaccess file is not present there, so I'm thinking that the two are conflicting. Any web dev champs able to see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a `/mrmikeanderson/` folder where the 2nd htaccess file is. The reason why the 
`RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=home` isn't being applied is because you are redirecting the `/` request to `mrmikeanderson/index.php`. So either change this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mrmikeanderson/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mrmikeanderson/index.php?page=home [L]
```

or change this rule in the other htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=home
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ index.php?page=home
```

Or you can change your `index.php` file to assume the variable `page` is `home` by default.

Comment: I did the first change, and that fixed it. Thanks for explaining it and not just giving the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mrmikeanderson/$1`

It looks like the regex `^(.*)$` will match anything including blank strings, which would conflict with `RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=home`

Edit:
Try using `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` in place of the `^(.*)$` which should give you:

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /mrmikeanderson/$1`

Comment: That broke it. I just get the "Index Of /" page.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set up a rewrite log to see what's going on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog